# How do you use COUNT(*) with find('list') in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 3, I had a model called Articles and a field called 'subject', and I ran into a roadblock trying to retrieve a list of the 100 most commonly-used article subjects.

The following code's resulting SQL selected *all* of the possible fields and *not* `COUNT(*)`:

```
$articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'subject',
    'valueField' => 'COUNT(*)'
])
->group('subject')
->order(['COUNT(*)' => 'DESC'])
->limit(100)
->toArray();
```

Then I remembered ["CakePHP’s ORM offers abstraction for some commonly used SQL functions."](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions). But the following code resulted in "Error: Function name must be a string":

```
$countFunc = $this->find()->func()->count('*');
$articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'subject',
    'valueField' => $countFunc
])
->group('subject')
->order([$countFunc => 'DESC'])
->limit(100)
->toArray();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Fortunately, [José](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684965/jos%C3%A9-lorenzo) tipped me off to this trick, which works like a charm:

```
$articles->find('list', [
    'keyField' => 'subject',
    'valueField' => 'count'
])
->select([
    'subject',
    'count' => $this->find()->func()->count('*')
])
->group('subject')
->order(['count' => 'DESC'])
->limit(100)
->toArray();
```

Comment: $this->Zendesks->find('list',['keyField'=>'company_id','valueField'=>'comment_id'])->where(['created_at >=' => $month3Start, 'created_at <=' => $month1End])
         ->select(['company_id','comment_id'=>$this->Zendesks->find()->func()->count('*')])->group('company_id');

Just copy my work over here, which may help others with more details. and thanks for your code!

Answer (score -1):

```
    $query = $articles->find();
    $query->select(['count' => $query->func()->count('*')]);
    $StaticPages = $query->toArray();
    $StaticPagesCount = $StaticPages[0]->count;
```

Comment: This doesn't use `find('list')` or generate the count of groups.