# Cakephp 3: Get count of messages in a thread

Tags: php, cakephp, group-by, count, cakephp-3.x

I have 3 tables (among others but not related to this) that are intertwined. These are the people, threads and posts. While designing my front-page I'm trying to show a count next to the thread name of the total posts it currently has. I can do it quite easily if it was SQL, but with cakephp I'm getting stumped as I'm not very familiar with the syntax.

The tables are connected like this (as of now):
Threads: person_id (who created thread)
Posts: thread_id (which thread it's related to), person_id (who posted).

This can be done by grouping with post_id as I tested it in sql. If you could be kind and show me a syntax in cakephp on how it should be done It'd be great!

Thanks

[Edit]
This is an sql syntax that works:

```
SELECT t.name, COUNT(p.id)
FROM posts p
JOIN threads t ON (p.thread_id = t.id)
GROUP BY t.name
```

Following that logic I've made it like this:

```
$query = $postsTable->find();
$query->select(['threads.name', $query->func()->count('posts.id')])
              ->matching('Threads')
              ->group(['threads.name']);
```

Comment: Is this your answer ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499893/how-do-you-use-count-with-findlist-in-cakephp-3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use COUNT(\*) with find('list') in CakePHP 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499893/how-do-you-use-count-with-findlist-in-cakephp-3)

Answer (score 0):

total count for a query containing group by clauses without having to rewrite the query in any way. For example, consider this query for retrieving article ids and their comments count.

```
$query = $posts->find();
$query->select(['post.post_id', $query->func()->count('Comments.id')])
    ->matching('Comments')
    ->group(['post.post_id']);
$total = $query->count();
```

After counting, the query can be used for fetching the associated records with:

```
$list = $query->all();
```

For more examples :

[Returning total records](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/query-builder.html#returning-the-total-count-of-records)

UPDATE : you just added data structer so should be like :

```
$query = $postsTable->find(); 
$query->select(['p.thread_id', 
$query->func()->count('t.id')]) 
->matching('Threads') 
->group(['p.thread_id']); 
$total = $query->count();
```

Comment: Not sure the way I made it is 100% correct.I'll update OP as I can't structure them here.

Comment: @Badrukk its because you are trying to equal `threat_name` and `post_id`, which is name is `varchar` and id is `integer` I updated answer try it and let me know for response.

Comment: I used the name to be more "readable" but even with id, I'd get the same outcome. Anyway I tried yours but it's still missing one of the posts. Only one post per thread is shown. Also, when passing it to the view atm with how it's currently structured I can't say do: $totalPosts->count($thread->id) as all are getting same count.

Comment: @Badrukk **Only one post per thread is shown** so its your query part then answer is right.

Comment: I didn't get what you said, but if you meant that it's correct then not really. One of the threads has 2 posts, another has 1 and the rest are 0. If I group by Posts.thread_id the result is: [Threads] => Array => [0] => thread_id => 6 AND [1] => thread_id => 8